# Removing double new line from string

Tags: python

So I have this problem for some reason some times I'm getting a string with two n/ n/ signs between first `<p> and <p><p>`, how could try to catch it and remove it?

look like this if I paste it

```
string = '<p>

    </p><p><span style="color: rgb(114, 114, 114);text-align: justify">Tutorials</span><br></p><p></p>'
```

if I look at this string from debugger then I see it like `<p>\n\n\<p><p>`

so basicaly I need to check if \n\n is between `<p> and <p><p>` then i have to remove it.

Comment: StackOverflow is not a code-writing service. Please read through the [Help Center](https://stackoverflow.com/help), in particular [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) If you run into a specific problem, research it thoroughly, search thoroughly here, and if you're still stuck post your code and a description of the problem. Also, remember to include [Minimum, Complete, Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). People will be glad to help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use string method replace:

```
s = s.replace("<p>\n\n\</p><p>", "<p></p><p>")
```

(or whatever you need replacing)

Comment: but it's a dynamic string i'm getting, some times it's comes like <p>\n\n\</p><p> and some times like <p></p><p>

Comment: Then I do not understand what you need. The statement above replaces all occurences. If there is none, it will replace none.